# Problema com JS/JQuery/JSON/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring

Estou com alguns problemas com JSON na minha aplicação e queria ver se vocês podem me ajudar, por favor.

A situação é a seguinte:

Tenho um método no meu controller que busca alguns itens:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buscaTodosCardapios", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String buscaTodosCardapios(Usuario usuario, Model model){
    JSONObject retorno = new JSONObject();
    try{        
        retorno.put("data", cardapioRepository.findBySubmenuIsNull());
    }catch (Exception ex){
        retorno.put("situacao", "ERRO");
        retorno.put("mensagem", "Falha ao iniciar produção!");
    }
    return retorno.toString();
}
```

Um arquivo JS que pega esses itens:

```
function buscaTodosCardapios(){
$.ajax({
    url: "buscaTodosCardapios",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: updateCardapios
});
}

function updateCardapios(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.cardapioId);
}
```

Retorna tudo OK:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que, como podem ver, o segundo console.log, não retorna nada e eu não consigo fazer ele pegar algum elemento de dentro do data. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

-EDIT-
Solução para quem precisar, foi só mudar para:

```
console.log(data.data[0].cardapioId);
```

Comment: Marque uma resposta se você encontrou a solução, para mais informações veja [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você esta retornando um array.

Use Isto

```
console.log(data.data[0].cardapioId);
```

Comment: Retorna o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cardapioId' of undefined

Comment: Exato Alterei agora para isto tente assim

Comment: Um pouco antes de abrir aqui, acabei testando desta forma e funcionou, de qualquer forma, muito obrigado!

Comment: Quando uma resposta conter a solução da sua pergunta, aceite ela como resposta não edite sua pergunta para isso

Answer (score 0):

Como você está trazendo um array de objetos, 
para conseguir acesso, terá que ser:

```
console.log(data.data[0].atributo);
```

Comment: Já tentei assim e me retorna o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cardapioId' of undefined

Comment: de um console.log(data[0]) e mostre o que aparece.

Comment: Deu tudo certo por aqui, já editei o post. Obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, quando vc utiliza na anotação @RequestMapping a instrução produces={"application/json"} 
você não precisa anotar com @RespondeBody. Você também não precisa que o retorno seja do tipo string, pode retornar diretamente o objeto e o Spring vai transforma-lo no formato json.